# excel nested Formula IF statements assistance

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

```
=IF([@[Date Last Revised]]>[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Date Last Revised]]+730,IF([@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]>[@[Date Last Revised]],[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]+730),IF([@[Date Last Revised]]=[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Biennial Review Date]]))
```

This is my function. It worked until I added the Last If statement. Because it was just showing a "False" if both the date last revised and date of biennial review where the same. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 2):

By formatting the formula as such:

```
=IF([@[Date Last Revised]]>[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Date Last Revised]]+730,
 IF([@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]>[@[Date Last Revised]],[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]+730),
IF([@[Date Last Revised]]=[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Biennial Review Date]]))
```

You can see the errant `)` at the end of the second IF.  It should be at the end of the formula:

```
=IF([@[Date Last Revised]]>[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Date Last Revised]]+730,
 IF([@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]>[@[Date Last Revised]],[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]+730,
IF([@[Date Last Revised]]=[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Biennial Review Date]])))
```

But this can be simplified as you are not using the false in the third formula to:

```
=IF([@[Date Last Revised]]>[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]],[@[Date Last Revised]]+730,
 IF([@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]>[@[Date Last Revised]],[@[Date of Last Biennial Review]]+730,[@[Biennial Review Date]]))
```

Comment: You're a huge help. Thank you!

Comment: @danyk if this worked for you, please consider marking as correct by clicking the check mark by the answer.